# Custom PhaseListener called twice in jsf 2

Tags: jsf-2

I was working with the PhaseListener in JSF 2.0. But it's methods are getting called twice every time.

```
@Override
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println("Start Phase "+arg0.getPhaseId()+" here the value "+ ++i +" object "+this);  
}
```

and output is like this

```
Start Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1 here the value 1 object com.phaseListener.MyPhaseListener@cc8c29
Start Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1 here the value 1 object com.phaseListener.MyPhaseListener@106054a
```

each time it is being called by two different objects.

Please let me know, why it is like so??

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps someone googling for this problem.

In my case, I moved from Glassfish 3 to Tomcat 7 and I noticed that my custom phase listener was being registered twice causing duplicated log entries.

In my web.xml I had a ConfigureListener which was required for Glassfish 3 but triggers a second registration on Tomcat 7:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I simply removed this block and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've registered your phase listener twice in the JSF application. The "why" for that is in turn not constuctively answerable. If you're bothered about the same phase listener being registered twice, just remove the second registration.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I am taking your blog for reference and I was hoping that you will answer, thanks for answering .Though I have not registered phase listener twice. My faces-config setting is                 <lifecycle>
<phase-listener>com.phaseListener.MyPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>

Comment: A less likely cause is that you've two JSF implementations in your runtime classpath.

Comment: <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JSF 2.1 (Mojarra 2.1.6-FCS)">
  <attributes>
   <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.jsf"/>
  </attributes>
 </classpathentry>

Comment: in my case...its also getting called twice.. is it a worry for  performances related issues , is it decrease the performances of the application?

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears if you are using Tomcat 7.0.4x. Try to downgrade Tomcat to at least 7.0.39 or below. The problem is very likely to be be resolved. I still do not know the reason but it works. Hope it helps.